# Tags referring to web services that check code

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

- There is a tag called [rubular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubular). Rubular is a website for testing Ruby regexes. As far as I see, the questions tagged with rubular tag only mention regex, and there is nothing particular about rubular. Sometimes, the poster claims that the behavior of rubular is different from the behavior of Ruby on a local machine, but it turns out that it was the poster's mistake.
- There is a tag called [jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsfiddle). JSFiddle is a website for testing HTML, JavaScript, and CSS codes. As far as I see, the questions tagged with JSFiddle tag only mention HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and there is nothing particular about JSFiddle except for a rare cases that mention some features of JSFiddle, which is not frequent enough to make it necessary to have such tag.

Since these are popular websites, the posters (mostly beginners in the respective fields) often link their question to these pages with their attempted code. But the questions have nothing to do with these websites. I don't think it makes any sense to have such tags. They should be removed. If there are similar tags that I don't mention referring to similar web services, they should be removed as well.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree.

The remit of Stack Overflow includes "tools commonly used by programmers." JSFiddle, for example, is a tool commonly used by programmers and so questions about it are on-topic. Of course there will be questions that aren't about it where the tag is included; feel free to remove the tag in these cases. Some incorrectly tagged questions are not, however, a reason to remove a tag completely.

This is actually a common problem, in quite a few tags. People using a tool but with a code question will often include the tool/IDE/GUI/environment because that's what they think they're using. They sometimes exclude the language 'cause it's not the tool... The best thing we can do is educate people and ensure questions are tagged correctly, so that they're easier to find.

Comment: What kind of question can you think of that is about rubular, or jsfiddle?

Comment: "How can I get JSFiddle to connect to an external resource" is one I remember @sawa. It's irrelevant to my point though, just because something's been mistagged doesn't mean that the tag shouldn't exist.

Comment: It is relevant. If there isn't a proper use of the tag, then all uses of the tag would be mistagging, and the tag shouldn't exist. Or, if proper use of the tag is rare, then the tag shouldn't exist.

Comment: If it's rare then a tag shouldn't exist? Tags are a categorisation system, like Linnaean taxonomy. Do we remove genus' from the tree because there aren't many species in it? If a tag is a useful categorisation then it's useful.

Comment: This, far too often do I see a c# question tagged with [visual-studio] for no reason, similarly, visual studio questions tagged with [c#]