# What is key to getting more attention?

Tags: discussion

Some questions get significantly more attentions than others. For example, [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262893/do-we-need-a-home) asked yesterday got more than a thousand views, while a question that I asked yesterday only gained little more than twenty. I do not know what makes such huge difference. I would like to learn how to get more attention. What was special about the question that I linked?

Comment: */seriousanswer* You should be looking at the **qualitative worth**, not the **quantitative worth**, of a question when writing it.

Comment: @Qix My question was "what was special about that question". And your answer is that it wasn't pointless. That means that most other questions, which are non-special, are pointless. Are you sure that is what you mean?

Comment: No, I'm saying **this** question is pointless.

Comment: @Qix That does not answer my question at all. It does not answer why that particular question gained so many views. Your comment is pointless.

Comment: You: `I would like to learn how to get more attention.` Me: `You should be looking at the qualitative worth, not the quantitative worth, of a question when writing it.` I think that's an answer.

Comment: @Qix No. What you cited is not a question. You didn't understand the question.

Comment: Alright. You: `What is key to getting more attention?` Me: `You should be looking at the qualitative worth, not the quantitative worth, of a question when writing it.` Better?

Comment: Or, You: `What was special about the question that I linked?` Me: `It wasn't as pointless as this one.` Still an answer.

Comment: @Qix This time, you pointed the question correctly, but didn't understand the question in context. I am asking what is the key to getting more attention as the particular question that I linked.

Comment: ITT: Why do people read some things and not others? - Because nobody reads everything. This goes for everything in life, not just MSO.

Comment: Here's a free complementary analysis of [your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262952/2246344). **1.** The title doesn't grab my attention (gives me the impression that the post's boring). **2.** There aren't any pictures (makes the post even more dull). **3.** There isn't any **special** *formatting* (again, it makes the post look more like a wall of text). **4.** Your posts doesn't have any humor or show any creativity. For suggestions/tips you'll need to subscribe to our ProWriter™ package for a minimum annual fee of £199.⁹⁹.

Answer (score 14):

There are all sorts of factors at work here. But the short answer is,

**A lot of posts look really boring**.

Nondescript titles, rambling introductions, vague problem statements, complaints everyone on SO has already heard 10,000 times... So to get folks to click through, read, and vote, it takes a bit of extra effort to make it look worth their while.

I'm not going to write about **these 5 crazy tricks that'll get you mega meta attention**, but you don't need that - just look around at the posts that *you* click through and read, and pay attention to the writing style, the attention to detail, the **unique, descriptive titles** that folks come up with. You'll figure it out...